# How do I change the ipykernel of an already existing notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook that I would like to run in kernel I made. The notebook was already made (in class example) so I was curious if there is a way to swap out the kernel types. I tried looking at the file with a text editor and comparing it with a jupyter notebook I created using the kernel I want to use but was unable to find anything interesting.